# grabbing information from another running process

Tags: python

i'm trying to do something where i need to get information from an already running application. I need to be able to grab a few simple pieces of information like some numbers. The program that I'm attempting to make is meant to work on top of the running application, sort of as an assistance to it, but itself will run independently. Do i need some sort of tool like IDA pro that goes through the instructions to be able to grab the information? I'm just looking for any information or direction on how to do this.

edit: I should specify that the software that I'm trying to get information from is commercial software made for windows. I need to be able to read the data from running process memory space somehow and use it in my program. It's something that is mostly online so maybe grabbing packets is another option? The information is definitely encrypted though, so I'm not sure if that's straightforward or feasible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a **lot** of different ways to handle interprocess communication, depending on what you are trying to do, what environment (language(s), operating system, hardware, etc.) you are using, security issues and other factors.

Wikipedia [has an article that you can read to get some general sense of the issues involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Files and sockets are very simple & straightforward ways to do this, with the advantage of being relatively secure and language-agnostic. Depending on performance requirements, those may be sufficient. Or you may need to work with shared memory or some other lower-level connection.

Hard to say more without specific requirements.

Comment: That does explain quite a bit. This is NOT normal cooperative interprocess communication. Rather, it is sneaking around and grabbing data. Which is not always a bad thing. But is usually not very easy. Windows is going to try and protect each process from each other process. Sniffing packets may be better, but if the packets are encrypted (e.g., https instead of http) then that is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: i should add that this information is clearly displayed on my screen in the window while the program is running, so it's not like it's hidden away

Comment: Then you may be able to do an automatic screen capture and then ocr and parse the image.

Comment: yeah, i definitely thought of that as an option, but it seems like the most roundabout way of doing it. Also wouldn't work while the program is minimized